# Two levels of sampling

Tags: python, random, sampling

I have a bunch of `Thing`s.

A `Thing` is a struct with a field, `source`, typed as a string.

Currently I get a deterministic sampled selection of `Things` by simply hashing the Thing.

```
def is_thing_sampled(t: Thing):
    hashed_thing = my_deterministic_hash(t);
    return hashed_thing % 100 < sample_size_pct;
```

Now I want to extend this function so that it additionally samples Thing of a specific source. If the source is `"foo"`, I want to do another level of sampling on it.

```
def is_thing_sampled(t: Thing):
   hashed_thing = my_deterministic_hash(t)
   base = hashed_thing % 100 < sample_size_pct;
   if base and t.source == "foo":
      # try to sample again. How do I do this?? 
      double_hash = my_deterministic_hash(hashed_thing)
      return double_hash % 100 < foo_sample_size_pct

    return base
```

What's the right approach? I'd love some pointers - I'm a total beginner at statistics.

Comment: "Can someone help me understand what's the right approach?" - first, can you help us understand *what you mean by "right"*? What specific problem are you trying to avoid? For example, does there appear to be a statistical bias in the results you get from your code? Does it not give usable results at all? or just what? And *what does "do another level of sampling" mean*? For example, are you trying to change the relative probability with which foo-sourced Things are chosen? Create two separate sample sets, a general one and a foo-specific one? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

We can use a `while` `loop` that depends on the number of `additional_samples` that you want:

```
def is_thing_sampled(t: Thing):
   hashed_thing = my_deterministic_hash(t)
   base = hashed_thing % 100 < sample_size_pct;
   if base and t.source == "foo":
      additional_samples = 1
      samples = 0
      while samples <= additional_samples:
         samples += 1
         double_hash = my_deterministic_hash(hashed_thing)
         base = double_hash % 100 < foo_sample_size_pct
         hased_thing = double_hash

    return base
```